# Assign specific page numbers to ms access report in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I have reports in ms access and I have specific startup page number for each report in my DB I want to give that specific start number to report as its first page number and +1 in it for other pages. How can I achieve it I tried doing reseting page number in VBA but I couldn't successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each report has a **fix** starting page number, you can simply change the textbox displaying the page number from

```
="Page " & [Page]
```

to

```
="Page " & [Page] + 19
```

for a report that should start on page 20.

If you need VBA to determine the starting number, use a Public Function, e.g.

```
Public Function RepPageStart(RepName As String) As Long

    Select Case RepName
        Case "Report A": RepPageStart = 19
        ' etc
    End Select
    ' or instead Select Case read the number from a table ...

End Function
```

and on the report:

```
="Page " & [Page] + RepPageStart([Name])
```

`[Name]` returns the report name.